# Race condition between signals

Tags: verilog, race-condition, blocking, test-bench

I've encountered a test bench which can essentially be boiled down to the below example: clock and signals are changed in the in the same timestep with blocking assignments. I believe this causes a race condition between the clock and the two ctrlX signals, but I was unable to prove in the EDA playground (I understand it's beyond my control). Am I correct that there is a race condition?
(EDA Playground link: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5yDX#&togetherjs=gkG5xewfNN)

```
module tb_example;


  reg clk = 1;
  reg [3:0] dff1,dff2;
  reg [3:0] ctrl1 = 'd0;
  reg [3:0] ctrl2 = 'd0;

  initial begin
    #10 ctrl1 = 'd1;
    #20 ctrl1 = 'd2;
    #10 ctrl1 = 'd3;
    #100 $finish;
  end

  always begin
    #5 clk = !clk;  
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,tb_example);
  end

  initial begin
    #10 ctrl2 = 'd1;
    #20 ctrl2 = 'd2;
    #10 ctrl2 = 'd3;
    #100 $finish;
  end

  always @ (posedge(clk)) begin
    dff1 <= ctrl1;
  end

  always @ (posedge(clk)) begin
    dff2 <= ctrl2;
  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a race condition because you are using blocking assignments for ctrlx and they are changing at the same time as `posedge clk`.  So, the values assigned to dffx are indeterminate and can vary from simulator to simulator.

One way to avoid this is to change ctrlx on the negedge of clk:

```
  reg clk = 0;
```